# Can't set cookie when using res.sendFile() in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When using **res.sendFile()** the **set-cookie** header is not received in the response.

```
app.get(sessionTracker, (req, res, next) => {
  res.cookie('tracker', '123a', {
    maxAge: 172800000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true
  });
  return res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'dist', 'index.html')).end();
});
```

**Response**

[image]

Comment: try this res.set('Set-Cookie', "myCookie=cookieValue;Path=/")

Comment: What tool are you looking at the response in?  Any chance it is respecting the `httpOnly: true,` and therefore not showing you the cookie?  Or, any chance you're not using an https connection which would prevent the cookie from being sent.

Comment: FYI, there's no `.end()` after `.sendfile()` and `.status(200)` is not necessary since that's the default status.  So, you can just do `res.sendFile(path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'dist', 'index.html'))` all by itself.

Comment: As an experiment, try removing both `httpOnly: true` and `secure: true` to see if either of those is preventing Express from sending the cookie or preventing your client tool from showing it.

Comment: i did try with only ```res.sendFile(path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'dist', 'index.html'))``` at the begining.

Comment: I have tried by disabling httpOnly and secure flags.

Comment: tried ```res.set('Set-Cookie', "myCookie=cookieValue;Path=/")```

Comment: using the postman tool

Comment: Uhhmmm.  `app.get()` needs a path as the first argument.  But you're saying (in a comment) that `sessionTracker` is middleware, not a path.  The express doc shows: `app.get(path, callback [, callback ...])`.  `path` and at least one callback are required.

Comment: Also, if `sessionTracker` tracker is middleware, is it possible that it's sending a  response and NOT calling `next()` so that your `res.cookie()` and `res.sendFile()` code never execute?

Comment: it was ```app.use()```, forgot to change while editing, anyways thank you

Comment: The issue was the file being served from the development server, not the express server. Only the API requests were reaching the express server, but the index.html file was coming from the development server.

Answer (score 1):

1. @Chandan  I was able to make this work, you dont need a .end()

   ```
    app.get("/sessionTracker", (req, res, next) => {
      res.cookie('tracker', '123a', {
       maxAge: 172800000,
       httpOnly: true,
       secure: true
      });
     return res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './', 'nu.json'));
   });
   ```
2. also make sure that the "sessionTracker" variable hasnt been mixed up.

Comment: What did you change or fix?  Your code looks pretty much the same.  Please describe in words what you think the OP's problem was.

Comment: "sessionTracker" is the middleware, **.end()** was used just to make sure the response has ended. Anyways thank you.

The issue was the file being served from the development server, not the express server. Only the API requests were reaching the express server, but the index.html file was coming from the development server.

Comment: i removeds the .end() and thought that the issue, althought it's not accurate so i tried sharing what worked for me, But @ChandanS glad you worked it out .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it doing this before:

```
<a href="/redirect-coaching">Coaching</a> 


router.get('/redirect-coaching', (req, res) =>
{
   res.redirect('/coaching')
})
```

And then:

```
router.get('/coaching', (req, res) =>
{
   res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../views/coaching.html'))
})
```

I know is a little bit hacky... but it works, and this sets the cookie.

If anyone could help with a more elegant solution i´ll be very grateful.